# Send error logs to Graylog in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error-log

What is the best approach to sending the error logs from my Magento site to Graylog?

Comment: You are better off using like sentry. But if you are set on using graylog you might be able to port this extension from m1 to m2 https://www.mgt-commerce.com/magento-graylog-log-management.html